# Spring MongoDB: Criteria methods non-static access

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongo

I'm writing a dynamic MongoDB query using `Aggregation` and `Criteria` like so.

```
Aggregation aggregation;
AggregationResults<DataContentResult> result;
List<DataContentResult> theResult;
try {
    aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                buildMatchCriteriaForAggregation(publisherId, filter)
                , buildGroupOperationForAggregation());

    result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, DataContent.class, DataContentResult.class);
    theResult = result.getMappedResults();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
private AggregationOperation buildMatchCriteriaForAggregation(Integer publisherId, Filter filterCriteria){
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.where("publisherId").is(publisherId);

    if (filterCriteria.getTa() != null) criteria.where("type").is(filterCriteria.getTa());
    if (filterCriteria.getPlz() != null) criteria.where("zip").is(ilterCriteria.getPlz());
    if (filterCriteria.getTbVerlag() != null) criteria.where("tbVerlagNr").is(filterCriteria.getTbVerlag());

    return Aggregation.match(criteria);
}
```

Now I know that I am supposed to access `Criteria` methods in a static way like `Criteria.where("something").is("something")`. But in my case, I need to specify my `Filter` criterion depending on their availability. And therefore I have to do it as above. This isn't working and the `criteria` object ends up empty every time for some reason.

What alternative method is recommended in this situation? Or is it that I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so the answer turned out to be quite simple as follows:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

criteria = criteria.where("publisherId").is(publisherId);
if(<condition>) criteria = criteria.orOperator(
                       Criteria.where("something").is("something"));
```